# calculating trailing 3 months revenue

Tags: apex, soql, batch, schedulebatch

I have an sObject, which has Sales_Rep_*c, Month*_c and Year_*c variables and corresponding revenue in Revenue*_c variable. For this combination, I want to create a new formula field to calculate the sum of trailing 3 months revenue. i.e. Feb,2014 would have sum of revenue from Nov,2013 to Jan,2014 How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you want calculate it? Is the object you mentioned is child and you want calculate it on parent?

Comment: @Birthus I want to create a formula field for calculating trailing 3 month revenue in the same object

Comment: Hmmm, I still have problem with understanding that. You said there is only one Sales_Rep_c, Month_c and Year_c, Revenue_c field per object, so how you want calculate 3 month sum from object that represent just 1 month? Or this object is updated each month?

Comment: yes sir. thats correct. Sorry if I was confusing. Basically I have historical monthly sales rep revenue since 2012, which gets updated every month with latest month entry.. I want to add a new formula field in the object to calculate trailing 3 months revenue for each month. so against every month I will have sum of past 3 month revenue...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to achieve your goal based on formula(You can't access history object).

If it have to be formula you have to create 2 more fileds to store historical value. then calculate sum of this fields.

But I strongly advice to calculate it based on trigger or batch job that will access historical data.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using a scheduled Batch job to accomplish this.  You could schedule it to run on the first of every month.  Using SOQL, you could easily pull the previous 3 months numbers, Sum them and update the field.

Below is a simple example of how this would work.  Obviously there is a bot that needs to be worked out by you, but this should give you a very start to the solution.

**Scheduled Class**

```
global class myScheduledClass implements Schedulable {

    public static String Sched = '0 0 02 F * ?';  //First Day of each month at 2AM

    global static String scheduleThis() {
        myScheduledClass mySchedClass = new myScheduledClass();
        return System.schedule('My Job', Sched, mySchedClass);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        MyBatchClass BatchJob = new MyBatchClass();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(BatchJob,50);         
    }
}
```

**Batch Class**

```
global class MyBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global final string query;

    global MyBatchClass(){
        //Create your SOQL string to grab all the sObjects you need
        query = 'select id, Name, Other_Fields__c from Your_Object__c';     
    } 

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope){
        List<Your_Object__c> updateObjs = new List<Your_Object__c>();
        for(Sobject s : scope){
            Your_Object__c obj = (Your_Object__c) s;
        }
        //Using this list of SObjects, you now need to query for the 3 previous months
        //I would suggest using a map to hold this data
        //Once you have this, you can sum the number and set the field on each custom object    
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('Batch Job Complete!');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for such detailed answer @sfdc_ninja. But I want to create a new formula field in the object to calculate trailing 3 month revenue. I dont want to use it in VF page, rather I want to show this metric in SFDC reporting..

Comment: I think a formula field is going to be very tough for this.  This is not a VF page, it is an apex class that runs to calculate the value once a month.  You would still be able to report on this field.